# how do I query sql for a latest record date but if the record has a message return that reocrd

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

[image: Table Example]

From this example table I need row 2 and 3.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images. Also take a look at [mcve].

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I can assume that you need single record for each compId, but you really need to be more specific, when you ask question

Comment: @Eugene Yes, I need single record for each compId

Comment: What if you have 2 records with comment for single comp ?

Comment: @jarlh SQL Server

Comment: @Eugene Your query return record 1 and 2 and I need record 2 and 3 because compId: 'A' has a message. Sorry I didn't understand your question earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want the latest non-empty message per `compID`, or the latest message if all messages are empty.

If so, you can use window functions:

```
select id, compID, date, message
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by compID 
            order by case when message is not null then 0 else 1 end, date desc
        ) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
order by id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d7b9eaa2f8b00140e0de6f5e483311f6)**:

```
id | compID | date       | message    
-: | :----- | :--------- | :----------
 2 | B      | 2020-03-27 | null       
 3 | A      | 2020-03-22 | Hello World
```

Comment: Your query return record 1 and 2 and I need record 2 and 3. CompId: 'A' with the latest date '2020-03-24' has no message so I want record 3 that has a message. But if both records dont have a message then I want the latest record.

Comment: @BilalKhan: yes, I got that, and that query should work as expected. What is the content of message in row 1, is it `null`?

Comment: @BilalKhan: I added a demo to my answer for your reference. This seems to work as expected.

Comment: Row 1 message is empty.

Comment: @BilalKhan: if you have an empty string instead of `null`, you need to change the `over()` clause of the window function `over(partition by CompID order by case when message <> '' then 0 else 1 end, date desc`

Comment: It worked, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This query should select what you need:

```
Select T.* 
from your_table T
Inner join (


Select compId, max(date) as maxDate
From your_table
Where message is not null 
Group by compId
Union 
Select compId, max(date) as maxDate
From your_table
Where compId not in (select compId from your_table where message is not null )
Group by compId

) Last on Last .compId = T.compId and Last.maxDate = T.date
```

Comment: Your query return record 1 and 2 and I need record 2 and 3 because compId: 'A' has a message. Sorry I didn't understand your question earlier.

Comment: I see, I've updated the query, check it out

Comment: I am getting same result as before.

Comment: Updated again. That must be it

Comment: Still getting same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM #tmp t JOIN (SELECT CompID, MAX(Date) AS DateMax, MAX(CASE WHEN Message IS NOT NULL THEN ID END) AS MsgMaxID
    FROM #tmp 
    GROUP BY CompID) agt ON (t.ID = agt.MsgMaxID OR (agt.MsgMaxID IS NULL AND t.CompID = agt.CompID AND t.Date = agt.DateMax))
```